# Java:: Use a mouse listener object in a different class

Tags: java, arrays, swing, graphics, paintcomponent

Hello people,

I am trying to write an animated character for a multitouch screen. I want my object to have 5 eyes and each of whose pupil to be dragged and dropped differently, within the eye of course.

I have tried to do it all in a single class and the problem seems to be assigning mouse handlers to each of the five pupils! In other words, if I move one pupil, all the pupils are moving.

Then, I resorted to using a bespoke class just to the pupil. When I use it by itself, the pupil is draggable. However, when I use it as an object in the eyes class, the pupil is static! No clicks registered, no mouse activity tracked.

I have looked at tutorials, other related issues with mouse handlers and could not make any progress. I changed the code a dozen times from various tutorials and suggestions before finally posting here. Any ideas where I am missing the cue? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I know I am yet to put the constraints on the pupil movement within the eye.

Code for main eyes class:

```
package rollEyes;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FiveEyes extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int SIZE = 512;
    private int a = SIZE / 2;
    private int b = a;
    private int r = 4 * SIZE / 5;
    private int n;
int circleSize=30;
Pupil dc = new Pupil(1);

    public FiveEyes(int n) 
    {
        super(true);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE));
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        a = getWidth() / 2;
        b = getHeight() / 2;
        int m = Math.min(a, b);
        r = 4 * m / 5;
        int r2 = Math.abs(m - r) / 2;


        int numOfEyes = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfEyes ; i++) 
            {
            Graphics2D g2d2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                double t = 2 * Math.PI * i / n;
                int x = (int) Math.round(a + r * Math.cos(t));
                int y = (int) Math.round(b + r * Math.sin(t));
                drawEyeSockets(g2d2, x,y, 2*r2,2*r2);
            }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
        @Override
            public void run() 
        {
                create();
            }
        });
    }

    public void drawEyeSockets(final Graphics2D g2, int x, int y, int w, int h)
    {
        g2.drawOval(x,y,w,h);
        dc.drawCircle(g2, x+12, y+12);
    }

    private static void create() 
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        FiveEyes fivey = new FiveEyes(5);
        f.add(fivey);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Code for the Pupil class:

```
package rollEyes;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Pupil extends JPanel 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int radius=50;
int x_after = 50;
int y_after = 50;
MouseHandler mh ;
private static int n =1;
public Pupil(int n) 
{
    super(true);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    drawCircle(g2d,x_after,y_after); 
}

public  void drawCircle(final Graphics2D g2d, int x, int y) 
{
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, radius/2, radius/2);
        mh = new MouseHandler();
        this.addMouseListener(mh);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(mh);
}

private static void create() 
{
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Pupil dc = new Pupil(n);
    f.add(dc);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            create();
        }
    });
}

private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter
{
    boolean circleClicked=false;
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        circleClicked = false;
    }   
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) 
    {
            circleClicked = true;
    }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) 
        {
            if (circleClicked) 
        {
            x_after = me.getX();
            y_after = me.getY();
            repaint();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have Pupil extend JPanel, but really shouldn't be doing that. Instead, use the concepts that you've learned in your current Pupil class -- how to draw a movable circle, and extend it in the larger FiveEyes class, only this time create a `List<Pupil>` and draw them.  My suggestions:

- Make Pupil not extend JPanel. Instead give it the machinery to draw circles in certain locations and to have that location changed.
- Also you will need to give it a way to recognize if its circle has been clicked by giving it a contains(Point p) method. One way to do this is to use a Shape object, or you can roll your own method.
- Give FiveEyes a `List<Pupil>` that in reality is an `ArrayList<Pupil>` and fill it with Pupil objects.
- In FiveEyes `paintComponent(...)` method, iterate through this List telling each Pupil to draw itself.
- In your FiveEyes MouseAdapter's `mousePressed(...)` method, iterate through your Pupil List to see if a Pupil has been clicked on. If so, move it.
- Alternatively, you could create a Pupil BufferedImage, put it into an ImageIcon, and put that into a JLabel, and then allow your FiveEyes class's MouseAdapter to drag the labels around.

Comment: Thanks. Does this approach mean that we cannot use objects which have their own mouse handling events in a parent class which does not by itself have any mouse/event handling functions?

Comment: @BalaKrishnaKolluru: the problem with having the eye use its own mouse listener is that the mouse motion will be relative to the eye object itself and not the container that holds it, and the latter is what matters to you. You want to move the eye *inside* of its container.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this code

```
    mh = new MouseHandler();
    this.addMouseListener(mh);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(mh);
```

must only be called once. You're adding millions of mouse handlers to the component!

And you need five instances of `Pupil`, one for each eye. Right now, you have only one, so of course the rendering will only yield one result.

Lastly, you must make sure that only one eye is "active" at a time (i.e. not all of them should receive mouse events or not all of them should process them).

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Had to make the suggested corrections for a solution.